# how to Toggle div:before in a click event

Tags: jquery, css

is that possible to toggle  Div:before in a click event

```
.div:before {
    content: '';
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #F3F3F4;
    border-left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
    top: calc(50% - 20px);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `toggle Div:before`? Show and hide?

Comment: No......................! but a workaround is answered check the posted answers.

Comment: yes show hide Div:before. is that possible

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a class on click and add the `::before` styles to the toggled class:

```
.div.active:before {
  ...
}

$('.div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On click you are add another class to the `.div` element define the rules like

```js
$('.div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

```css
.div:before {
  content: 'before';
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #F3F3F4;
  border-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 20px);
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.div.clicked:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">click to toggle</div>
```